# Python 2.7 - unable to set/get a session cookie value

Tags: python, python-2.7, session, cookies, python-requests

I keep going in circles on trying to save a cookie and get its value but I keep getting errors. It seems to save the cookie with the following code:

```
    account = "Mario"
    
    session = requests.Session()
    
    session.post("http://127.0.0.1")
    
    cookie_obj = requests.cookies.create_cookie(domain='127.0.0.1', name='account', value=account)
    
    session.cookies.set_cookie(cookie_obj)
```

Then when I try to get the cookie it just prints { }:

```
    import requests
    
    session = requests.Session()
    
    request = session.get("http://127.0.0.1")
    
    print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

Am I missing something? I found too many websites with too many suggestions

Comment: Your second session is separate from the first session since you recreated it using `session = requests.Session()`, and also the server it connected to didn't set any cookies.

Comment: For a working example, try `response = session.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?k1=v1&k2=v2")`, and then `print(session.cookies.get_dict())`

Comment: Also, for the first example, you need to set the cookie first *before* making the request to the server - the server will not receive a cookie without it being set beforehand.

Comment: I thought I might have been resetting the session. Is there a way to access the session from the first page?

Comment: By following exactly what I have commented, i.e. `print(session.cookies.get_dict())` immediately after a request (e.g. `session.get`, `session.post`, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your help on this one. I ran some more tests and found out that sessions don't work the same on python as php. I was able to pickle to save/load pages over all my pages